# Problema con lista - [UnsupportedOperationException]

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

El siguiente es el código completo en donde me he estrellado inesperadamente con un error seguramente conceptual mío a la hora de trabajar con mi lista `dataList`, no lo tengo claro.

```
public class Test {
  private List<String> dataList;
  private void process1() {
    dataList=new ArrayList<>();
    dataList.add("Account");
    dataList.add("Name");
    dataList.add("Occupation");
    System.out.println(dataList);
    dataList.add("Age");
    System.out.println(dataList);
  }

  private void process2() {
    String[] data={"Account","Name","Occupation"};
    dataList=Arrays.asList(data);
    System.out.println(dataList);
    dataList.add("Age");       // <-- ERROR!! [UnsupportedOperationException]
    System.out.println(dataList);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().process2();
  }
}
```

En `process1` creo mi lista `dataList=new ArrayList<>();` de la manera mas común, después le asigno datos e imprimo sin problema alguno, veo en pantalla cada valor, todo Ok.

En el metodo `process2`, instancio la lista a partir de valores del arreglo `data`, `dataList=Arrays.asList(data);`, los imprime debidamente también, pero es al momento de querer agregar otro dato cuando salta un [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).

Vengo de la documentación pero aun así ¿Que es exactamente lo que estoy violando al intentar almacenar más datos con esa implementación de mi `dataList`?

***PD***:
*Jamas llamo a los dos métodos simultáneamente, expongo el código fuente así para ser lo mas descriptivo posible con el problema, gracias.*

Comment: el método `Array.asList(a)` devuleve una lista con tamaño fijo que no se puede modificar.  Quizá esto te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389012/how-to-add-elements-in-list-when-used-arrays-aslist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Que es exactamente lo que estoy violando al intentar almacenar más datos con esa implementación de mi dataList?

El método [asList](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L2827) retorna un objeto mutable y tal como se muestra en su código fuente:

```java
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
      return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

Devuelve un objeto de tipo `ArrayList` pero no es el `ArrayList` del paquete `java.util.ArrayList`, sino, es el [ArrayList](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L2834) que está definido de forma anidada en la clase `Arrays`.

Como el objeto que retorna `asList` es mutable, los elementos de la lista se podrán modificar.

**Por ejemplo:**

```java
String[] a = {"A", "B", "C"};
List<String> data = Arrays.asList(a);
data.set(0, "D");
System.out.println(data.get(0));
```

Con esto comprobamos que si se puede modificar los elementos de la lista, sin embargo, el tamaño de esta lista debe ser fija.

**¿Por qué esta sentencia da error?**

```java
dataList.add("Age");       // <-- ERROR!! [UnsupportedOperationException]
```

Porque la lista fue definido con un tamaño fijo, por lo tanto, no se puede agregar ni eliminar elementos, de lo contrario, el tamaño ya no sería fijo. Esa es la razón del porque da el error.

En el código fuente de la clase anidada `ArrayList` no se ve como tal la implementación del método `add` y esto se debe porque lo hereda de la clase `AbstractList`, que a su vez, esta clase es subclase de `AbstractCollection` (en esta clase es donde está la implementación del método `add`).

Entonces en el código fuente de la clase [AbstractCollection](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#L251) se ve claro de como implementaron el método `add`:

```java
 public boolean add(E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

Esto nos afirma que de forma directa lanza la excepción al invocar el método `add`.

Una solución a esta excepción es crear un objeto de tipo `ArrayList` y pasarle al constructor el objeto que retorna el método `asList`.

```java
dataList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data));
```

De este modo, podremos usar el método `add` sin ningún problema.

Comment: "De este modo, el puntero implícito dataList apuntará a un objeto mutable". Esto no es correcto, lo que ocurre es que el constructor de `ArrayList` que recibe un `Collection` pide los elementos de esta colección como un arreglo y lo referencia internamente. Por lo que como ahora tienes un objeto de tipo `java.util.ArrayList` puedes manupular sus datos sin problema, dado que la estructura subyacente siempre es un arreglo, aun los elementos los haya sacado de una Lista no modificable.

Comment: @E.Betanzos *Nunca dijiste porque era incorrecto* El método `asList` retorna la dirección base de un objeto inmutable (`dataList` apuntaría a la dirección base de un objeto inmutable), es decir, no puedes modificar el contenido de ningún atributo y es verdad, porque en el mismo código fuente se lo ve clarito. Sin embargo, si creas un objeto de tipo `ArrayList` del paquete `java.util.ArrayList`, el objeto será mutable debido a que, es posible modificar el atributo de dicho objeto y por ende, el puntero `dataList` apuntará a la dirección base de un objeto mutable, porque si se puede modificar.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Un ejemplo puede ser esto: `var x = new StringBuilder("Hola");` y `var y = new String("Hola")`. El puntero `x` apuntará a la dirección base de un objeto mutable y el puntero `y` apuntaría a un objeto inmutable.

Comment: Lo primero que debemos tener claro es que en Java no existen los punteros, existen referencias, que se parecen pero no son iguales. Segundo, el método `asList` NO retorna un objeto inmutable sino una lista de tamaño fijo, por lo que no podemos agregar ni eliminar elementos. Tercero, lo que incorrecto es decir que por el simple hecho de que `ArrayList` y como le pasamos la lista "inmutable" en el constructor, ya podremos modificarla porque los estamos haciendo a través del `ArrayList`.

Comment: Si ese constructor de `ArrayList` lo que hiciera, en vez de copiar los elementos de la lista "inmutable" hacia su estructura interna, fuera crear un Adaptador que se limitase a invocar los métodos correspondientes de la lista "inmutable" seguiríamos teniendo los mismos problemas.

Comment: Java no tiene soporte para punteros, es verdad, sin embargo, internamente, sigue siendo un puntero, de lo contrario, no sería posible acceder a las direcciones de memoria del objeto.  El método `asList` no retorna como tal una lista de tamaño fijo, sino un objeto que no se puede modificar, en su  [código fuente](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L2827) se ve claro lo que digo.

Comment: *como le pasamos la lista "inmutable" en el constructor, ya podremos modificarla...* Nunca dije eso. Lo que mencioné fue que se pasaba la referencia del objeto que retornaba `asList`, en la cual, el constructor de la clase `ArrayList` se encargaría de copiar los elementos de una lista no modificable hacia una que si se pueda alterar. El concepto de "mutable" y "inmutable" es correcto en este caso, mirar este [enlace](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_inmutable).

Comment: Es más, puedes revisar el código fuente del ArrayList del paquete `java.util.ArrayList` y ahí mismo se verá que su atributo no tiene el "final". En cambio, la clase `ArrayList` del paquete `java.util.Arrays` si tiene un atributo con el "final", es imposible modificar su contenido despues de haberle asignando un elemento, por eso el objeto que retorna el método asList es inmutable.

Comment: @E.Betanzos [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106139/discussion-between-mrdave1999-and-e-betanzos).